# Drupal 8 MVC: is there a Model?

Tags: 8

Coming from a Drupal background, I am quite thrilled at the idea of working with drupal 8 and symfony proper OOP and MVC practice. 
Right now I I am building a module with a service and a controller and I am at a loss regarding where to put my data fetching logic (that should be used by both).
Understanding MVC policy I should put it in some kind of "model" structure but I can't find anything about that in Drupal documentation (sadly a bit lacking at the moment). 
So what is the Drupal way for this?

Comment: Start point for understand database layer in Drupal 8 - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/database/8
There is a buch of module example that can help you - https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

Comment: You may not even need a data fetching code because you could re-use the existing entity manager service to load entities.

Comment: I do use entityQuery (and sql query) to fetch data but to me it is data fetching code.

Comment: As mradclif pointed out, use a service(custom or from core).

Answer (score 5):

Your data-fetching logic should be in its own service(s).

Symfony and by extension Drupal are not traditional implementations of the MVC architecture as there's no separate Model layer, like for instance in CodeIgniter.

One of the most important features in Symfony and Drupal are services, which are (or should be :p ) independent and reusable implementations of various functionalities.

So if you want data-fetching logic, then you can create your own service that does that and use that service in your controller, instead of polluting it with the queries (entity queries or otherwise).

I'll leave with a comment from Fabien Potencier (the creator of Symfony):

"It's up to you to create your model by hand or use any other tool, like an ORM" [...]I don't like MVC because that's not how the web works. Symfony2 is an HTTP framework; it is a Request/Response framework."

This statement might be debatable, but what I want to show here is the intent behind the choice of leaving out a well defined Model layer.